# date picker JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, picker

I got the departure time working  and the – but how do I add a `date picker` in the code:

This what I try to do :

The user does the following:

> 1. enter start location
> 2. enter end location
> 3. pick time
> 4. pick date
>      5.clicks on Get Directions

But I do not know how to get the date picker to work

The link is the following:

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/matthewclose/pen/oYoWvO)

Thank you

Comment: it works fine for me on chrome

Comment: The code seems to work. What exactly is the problem? Did you created the codepen or ar you using it as an example?

Comment: Do I not know how to make the date picker to work with rest of the code - so if the person selects Sunday it should come up with a different list.